# How can i call all uploaded products on ebay

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I want to fetch all list of products from ebay because I want to store them to my database. I checked some methods like `GetItemRequest`, `GetMultipleItems` and `GetSingleItem` but they all required item-id. I need to fetch all without any item id.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to call sellers product list then you must have to pass from and to date. Now, for me its working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <GetSellerListRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
                  <RequesterCredentials>
                    <eBayAuthToken>$authToken</eBayAuthToken>
                  </RequesterCredentials>
                  <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
                  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
                  <StartTimeFrom>$startTimeForm</StartTimeFrom> 
                  <StartTimeTo>$startTimeTo</StartTimeTo>
                  <EndTimeFrom>$endTimeFrom</EndTimeFrom>
                  <EndTimeTo>$endTimeTo</EndTimeTo>
                  <UserID>testuser_kanika</UserID>
                  <Pagination>
                    <EntriesPerPage>$itemPerPage</EntriesPerPage>
                    <PageNumber>$pageNumber</PageNumber>
                  </Pagination>
                  <OutputSelector>ItemArray.Item.ItemID</OutputSelector>
                  <OutputSelector>PaginationResult</OutputSelector>
                </GetSellerListRequest>
```